# Google Assistant - data storage (history of conversation)

Tags: actions-on-google, google-assistant

I can't find any Google's clear statement about the storage of data (history - Google Assistant).

Is there anyone here who knows the answer/s or knows who should I write to? I wrote to Google's helpdesks and they all say that they don't know and they don't deal with such issues...

It's all about Google Assistant (agent built on Google Actions):

1. User turns off history recording or deletes history. Is this history deleted on Google's servers, so it no longer exists?
2. User doesn't delete the history - it is being constantly recorded. Does Google have any access to conversation history or this access have only the user and the developer of the Assistant's app and it is encrypted, so Google can't "read" it?
3. It is possible to disable any conversation history on Google Assistant, so it is never being recorded?

Thanks!